# Entity error when there is no input DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, sqlexception

```
internal class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string SurName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime DeathDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Gender gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Father { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Mother { get; set; }



 public Person(string surName, string lastName, DateTime birthDate, Gender gender, string father, string mother)
    {
        SurName = surName;
        LastName = lastName;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        this.gender = gender;
        Father = father;
        Mother = mother;
    }
```

I have dont have [required] by DeathDate, still it only crashes when there is no input for DeathDate.

The error shown in debugger when i want to add them to the database

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll

```
private void AddPersonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeathDateDatePicker.SelectedDate == null)
        {
             Person personsntDeath = new Person(
                SurNameTextBlock.Text.Trim(),
                LastNameTextBlock.Text.Trim(),
                BirthDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value,
                (Gender)SexComboBox.SelectedItem,
                FatherTextBox.Text.Trim(),
                MotherTextBox.Text.Trim());

            personsntDeath.InsertIntoDB();
        }
        else
        {

            Person persons = new Person(
                SurNameTextBlock.Text.Trim(),
                LastNameTextBlock.Text.Trim(),
                BirthDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value,
                DeathDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value,
                (Gender)SexComboBox.SelectedItem,
                FatherTextBox.Text.Trim(),
                MotherTextBox.Text.Trim());

            persons.InsertIntoDB();
        }

        mainWindow.Content = new PageOverviewPersons(mainWindow);
    }
```

If there is no input in DeathDatePicker i want it to be null in my database. It comes back with the value "{01/01/0001 00:00:00}"

```
public bool InsertPerson(Person persons)
    {
        using (DataBaseContext ctx = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.Persons.Add(persons);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create a family tree program.

Comment: Why don't you make it nullable `DateTime?`?

Comment: Did you try marking `DeathDate` optional?

Comment: Did try both those things

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a value type it can not be null unless you define it as nullable using `?` operator

```
public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I did try this but still gives a error : Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: did you update the database after changing the property to nullable? if you are using code-first just add migration

Comment: It just gives me a new error : Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: can you check the inner exception for more details? so you can know what property caused the error

Comment: @KylianNijdam If you're seeing that when trying to run a migration, it normally means the user defined in your connection string doesn't have the correct permissions for modifying tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
public DateTime DeathDate { get; set; }
```

to

```
public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; } //Nullable
```

And check if its got value by using `DateTime?.HasValue` property.

```
if (!DeathDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue)
{
    //  Your code here
}
```